# How to Zlib inflate an list of bytes in Elixir?

Tags: zlib, elixir

Given a binary in Elixir which represents a compressed file, how can I pass them to Erlang's zlib to inflate?

```
compressed = <<120, 218, 237, 125, 123, 115, 28, 71, 126, ...>>
```

I have tried:

```
z = :zlib.open()
uncompressed = :zlib.inflate(z, compressed)
:zlib.close(z)
```

Error returned is:

```
** (ErlangError) erlang error: :einval
               :zlib.call/3     
               :zlib.inflate/2
```

Expects an "iodata" as an argument, so maybe I just need to convert it?

Comment: It seems like you need to call `:zlib.inflateInit(z)` first. At least for me, that gives me `:data_error` instead of `:einval`.

Comment: Wow, that was totally it, thank you.  If you want to make it an answer, I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After opening the zlib port, you need to call `inflateInit` on it before calling `inflate`:

```
z = :zlib.open()
:zlib.inflateInit(z)
uncompressed = :zlib.inflate(z, compressed)
:zlib.close(z)
```

Comment: Just had the same problem with deflating. Need to call `deflateInit` before deflating.

Comment: I'm doing this exact thing; :zlib.inflate returns an io list ... a list of binaries that have to be combined.  I used Enum.into(uncompressed, <<>>).